# How to instantiate and use Propel effectively

Tags: php, propel

Ok, I got Propel installed with Composer, and I set it up via the "Easy Way" `propel init`

Now I'm trying to execute this example, as per shown in Propel documentation:

```
<?php
/* initialize Propel, etc. */

$author = new Author();
$author->setFirstName('Jane');
$author->setLastName('Austen');
$author->save();
```

But there's nothing about how to properly "initialize Propel".

Tried:

```
use php_orm\php_orm\TblEmpresa;

$empresa = new TblEmpresa();
$empresa->setName('Teste');
```

But it just results in an error: Class 'php_orm\php_orm\TblEmpresa' not found in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per shown on other similiar questions, this problem was solved by describing the exact path to the php generated class in compose.json, like:

```
{
    "require": {
    "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev"
},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": ""},
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/bin/orm/orm/",
            "vendor/bin/orm/orm/Base/",
            "vendor/bin/orm/orm/Map/"
        ]
    }
}
```

and then running on terminal:

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recurring question among Propel beginners.

Here is a presentation that pretty much holds your hand through the entire process of getting up and running with Propel (using the "easy way" with `propel init`).

[Up & Running with Propel2 (Presented at OpenWest 2016)](http://pencilinthehand.com/wp-content/Propel%20Quickstart%20v13.pdf)

This should help you get through your issue, since it has for several others in your condition.  If it doesn't, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I'll try it later on, I was about to choose you last option, building my own orm (or a tiny piece of it). Good job by the way, and thanks for sharing!

Comment: Ok, now the code finds the file TblEmpresaQuery which extends the same file present in \Base directory. But still, returns me the message: Exception has occurred.
Fatal error: Class 'propel\propel\Base\TblEmpresaQuery' not found. Strange is that this file actually exists in the path....

Comment: The code is most likely looking somewhere other than where the file is located. This might be due to a change to your setup. When this happens to me while learning a new technology, it is usually a sign that I need to start afresh to get a clean setup.